# Accessibility Inspector not working on Xcode Version 13.3 on macOS Monterey Version 12.3

Tags: ios, swift, accessibility, xcuitest, ios13.3

I launch the Accessibility Inspector from within Xcode but it doesn't let me interact with elements in the simulator.

I relaunched Xcode, the Accessibility Inspector and simulator but it doesn't seem help.

The simulator I'm using is for iPhone 12.

[Accessibility Inspector not working on iPhone 12 simulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jJppd.png)

Any ideas?

Comment: It hasn't been working for a while for me either...

Comment: Does it work on any of the other simulators? I suspect not. I rarely upgrade Xcode quickly and when I do I retain my old installs (by renaming them) and manually downloading the latest version. I’d suggest doing that in the future. Old version can still be downloaded from Apple.

Comment: Yea... I also opened a topic on Apple's Developer forum today with the exact same issue. Accessibility Inspector is totally broken in Xcode 13.3, the only way to make it work is to go back to 13.2.1, which is quite sad if you use SPM in your project, the Package.resolved thing is not compatible between the two versions of Xcode and switching between them is a pain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apple often seems to inadvertently break testing tools, especially the Test Recorder and Accessibility Inspector. I'd suggest you use an older version of Xcode until you have a strong need to upgrade. These can be downloaded from Apple's [More Downloads](https://developer.apple.com/download/all/?q=xcode) page.

If you wish to retain 13.3 I'd suggest renaming it to `Xcode_13_3.app` prior to installing a prior version, which will install as `Xcode.app`.

I also highly advise against using the App Store to keep your Xcode up to date (if that's what you're doing). Instead manually download new versions via the link above and rename old versions (in case you find broken things in the new one) also as described above.

Comment: This is so true and it raises a few questions about how and if Apple engineers are actually using the provided testing tools if things are broken so often...

Comment: @Andy ‍♂️I never use either of those tools. They're pretty terrible once you're handy in the debugger. Or maybe I never gave them a chance because they were always broken.

Comment: I only use them for Accessibility stuff and UI testing (more like debugging UI tests) and I found Accessibility Inspector to be pretty useful. I filled a bug report via Feedback Assistant, will see if apple fixes this.

Answer (score 5):

I know that is very painful when something not working after updates, but my friend told me that we can use real device instead of simulator with Accessibility Inspector. It working fine, even convenient usage of real device with this app. Pick your device over here, when it is connected to Mac

[image]